# Estado del cursor incorrecto ¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

Tags: base-de-datos, eclipse, ms-access, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo una interfaz para a traves de ella meter informacion a una base de datos y corregí el problema anterior que era que no tenia privilegios para usar una BD, ahora me lanza el siguiente error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 estado del cursor incorrecto: cursor indicado no está posicionado en una fila para sentencia UPDATE, DELETE, SET, o GET: ; Posición actual del resultado de la consulta es después del último registro
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getString(UcanaccessResultSet.java:769)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.mostrar(FrmPrueba.java:198)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.<init>(FrmPrueba.java:123)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.main(FrmPrueba.java:211)
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 estado del cursor incorrecto: cursor indicado no está posicionado en una fila para sentencia UPDATE, DELETE, SET, o GET: ; Posición actual del resultado de la consulta es después del último registro
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getObject(UcanaccessResultSet.java:615)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getString(UcanaccessResultSet.java:763)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: estado del cursor incorrecto: cursor indicado no está posicionado en una fila para sentencia UPDATE, DELETE, SET, o GET: ; Posición actual del resultado de la consulta es después del último registro
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getColumnInType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getObject(UcanaccessResultSet.java:609)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: estado del cursor incorrecto: cursor indicado no está posicionado en una fila para sentencia UPDATE, DELETE, SET, o GET: ; Posición actual del resultado de la consulta es después del último registro
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

El código de la interfaz es este:

```
package Conexion;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class FrmPrueba extends JFrame {


      ;

     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    JTable Muebles;
    JScrollPane jspPrueba;
    DefaultTableModel dtmPrueba;
    String titulos [] = {"ID", "Precio", "Categoria", "Descripcion", "Precio A"};

    JTextField txtID, txtPrecio, txtCategoria, txtDescripcion, txtPrecioA;
    JLabel lblID, lblPrecio, lblCategoria, lblDescripcion, lblPrecioA;

    Connection con = null;
    JButton btnGuardar, btnNuevo;   

    public FrmPrueba (){

        //setVisible(true);

        btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnNuevo = new JButton("Nuevo");

        txtID = new JTextField();
        txtPrecio = new JTextField();
        txtCategoria = new JTextField();
        txtDescripcion = new JTextField();

        txtPrecioA = new JTextField();


        lblID = new JLabel("ID");
        lblPrecio = new JLabel("Precio");
        lblCategoria = new JLabel("Categoria");
        lblDescripcion = new JLabel("Descripcion");
        lblPrecioA = new JLabel("Precio A");


        dtmPrueba = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
        Muebles = new JTable(dtmPrueba);
        jspPrueba = new JScrollPane (Muebles);  

        add(jspPrueba);

        add(txtID);
        add(txtPrecio);
        add(txtCategoria);
        add(txtDescripcion);
        add(txtPrecioA);
        add(lblID);
        add(lblPrecio);
        add(lblCategoria);
        add(lblDescripcion);
        add(lblPrecioA);

        add(btnGuardar);
        add(btnNuevo);

        jspPrueba.setBounds(20,200,550,200);

        lblID.setBounds(20,20,200,20);
        txtID.setBounds(120,20,200,20);

        lblPrecio.setBounds(20,50,100,20);
        txtPrecio.setBounds(120,50,200,20);

        lblCategoria.setBounds(20,80,100,20);
        txtCategoria.setBounds(120,80,200,20);

        lblDescripcion.setBounds(20,110,100,20);
        txtDescripcion.setBounds(120,110,200,20);

        lblPrecioA.setBounds(20,140,110,20);
        txtPrecioA.setBounds(120,140,200,20);

        btnNuevo.setBounds(390, 100, 100, 25);
        btnGuardar.setBounds(390, 140, 100, 25);

        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                btnGuardarActionPerform(evt);
            }
        });

        btnNuevo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                btnNuevoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


        Muebles.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                tblPruebaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        mostrar();

        }

        protected void btnNuevoActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtID.setText("");
            txtPrecio.setText("");
            txtCategoria.setText("");
            txtDescripcion.setText("");
            txtPrecioA.setText("");
    }

        protected void tblPruebaMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int file = Muebles.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
            txtID.setText(Muebles.getValueAt(file, 0).toString());
            txtPrecio.setText(Muebles.getValueAt(file, 1).toString());
            txtCategoria.setText(Muebles.getValueAt(file, 2).toString());
            txtDescripcion.setText(Muebles.getValueAt(file, 3).toString());
            txtPrecioA.setText(Muebles.getValueAt(file, 4).toString());

    }

    protected void btnGuardaractionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try{
            con = ConexionAccess.getConexion();
            if(txtID.getText().equals("")){
                String sql = "Insert into tbl(Id, Precio, Categoria, Descripcion, PrecioA values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtPrecio.getText());
                pst.setString(3, txtCategoria.getText());
                pst.setString(4, txtDescripcion.getText());
                pst.setString(5, txtPrecioA.getText());
                int n = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(n>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se registró de forma correcta");
                }

            }else{
                String sql = "update tbl set Id = ?, set = Precio, Categoria = ?, Descripcion = ?, PrecioA = ? where Id = ?)";  
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtPrecio.getText());
                pst.setString(3, txtCategoria.getText());
                pst.setString(4, txtDescripcion.getText());
                pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(txtPrecioA.getText()));
                int n = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(n>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se actualizó de forma correcta");
                }
            }}catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        mostrar();
        txtID.setText("");
        txtPrecio.setText("");
        txtCategoria.setText("");
        txtDescripcion.setText("");
        txtPrecioA.setText("");
        mostrar();

    }   

    public void mostrar (){
        try{
            con = ConexionAccess.getConexion();
            DefaultTableModel MUEBLELOS= (DefaultTableModel) Muebles.getModel();
            String dts[] = new String[5];
            String sql = "select * from Muebles";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()); 
                dts[0] = rs.getString(1);
                dts[1] = rs.getString(2);
                dts[2] = rs.getString(3);
                dts[3] = rs.getString(4);
                dts[4] = rs.getString(5);
                MUEBLELOS.addRow(dts); 

          Muebles.setModel(MUEBLELOS);     
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        FrmPrueba mi = new FrmPrueba(); 
        mi.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mi.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mi.setLayout (null);
        mi.setTitle ("Mueblelo | ¡Bienvenido!");
        mi.setSize(600, 500);
        mi.setVisible(true);
        //Connection on = ConexionAccess.obtenerConexion();


            }   

   public FrmPrueba(String title, GraphicsConfiguration gc, JTable Muebles,
            JScrollPane jspPrueba, DefaultTableModel dtmPrueba,
            String[] titulos, JTextField txtId, JTextField txtPrecio,
            JTextField txtCategoria, JTextField txtDescripcion,
            JTextField txtPrecioA, JLabel lblId, JLabel lblPrecio,
            JLabel lblCategoria, JLabel lblDescripcion, JLabel lblPrecioA,
            Connection con, JButton btnGuardar, JButton btnNuevo) {
        super(title, gc);
        this.Muebles = Muebles;
        this.jspPrueba = jspPrueba;
        this.dtmPrueba = dtmPrueba;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.txtID = txtId;
        this.txtPrecio = txtPrecio;
        this.txtCategoria = txtCategoria;
        this.txtDescripcion = txtDescripcion;
        this.txtPrecioA = txtPrecioA;
        this.lblID = lblId;
        this.lblPrecio = lblPrecio;
        this.lblCategoria = lblCategoria;
        this.lblDescripcion = lblDescripcion;
        this.lblPrecioA = lblPrecioA;
        this.con = con;
        this.btnGuardar = btnGuardar;
        this.btnNuevo = btnNuevo;
    }

protected void btnGuardarActionPerforme (ActionEvent evt) {


    }




    protected void btnGuardarActionPerform(ActionEvent evt) {


    }


    }
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Es muy importante que leas [ask] y tambien [mcve]. Es muy dificil contestarte si no podes especificar claro donde tenes tu problema

Comment: Lo que busco que es que funcione mi interfaz. Yo usando este programa quiero METER DATOS A LA BD, la conexión YA ESTÁ HECHA, pero mis datos siguen sin guardarse en la interfaz que está conectada a la base de datos, EL PRIMER CÓDIGO que dejé es el ERROR QUE ME DA, trato de resolver ese error. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Anteriormente en la linea String sql = "select * from Muebles"; me daba error porque Muebles era el nombre de mi tabla y tenía otro, pero me aparece el error de arriba, el cual pienso yo  que es un error derivado a esta linea.

Comment: Es fundamental que leas los enlaces que ya te pasaron, opino igual que @gbianchi, falta información, ¿En que línea ocurre el error? ¿Qué es lo que buscas? ¿Qué hace tu programa? en definitiva, algo más de contexto. También agrega el stack trace completo. son solo sugerencias para que puedas mejorar tu pregunta y por consiguiente mejores las chances de obtener una buena respuesta. Suerte.

Comment: Ya me dieron una solución. Pero igual muchas gracias.

Comment: @LRHDZ ¿ obtuviste una solución ? Puedes agregarla.